# how to display waveform while radio stream is playing?

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make a radio app, i found this package [flutter_radio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radio_player) which manages the radio stream, now i want to display a waveform while the radio is playing, how can i do that? i only found packages that records sound or use an audio file but not a stream.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask